# Strange issue in header location redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have three websites hosted (example1.com, example2.com, example3.com) on a server. There is a page (test.php) on example1.com with just code below inside it:

```
<?php
  header('Location:http://example2.com/a.php');
?>
```

When I browse test.php it goes to http://example1.com/a.php . it doesn't understand it is another domain url, it tried to find the page on itself.

but when I put http://google.com instead of example2.com/a.php it works correct. I really get confused.

What is the problem ? Should I set some configuration on the server?

( I am administrator of the hosting server ).
Ps. The server is behind a pound server.

Here's the Firebug Net output for example1.com/test.php

```
Response Headers: 

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 09:03:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Location: http://example1.com/a.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 21
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Request Headers:

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  mycookie
Host    example1.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

Comment: Are you sending a 3xx status code? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: yes, 302 status is logged in access_log.

Comment: Can you show the complete HTTP headers (use wget, curl, firebug, etc)

Comment: There should be a space before the http. What happens if you put 'http://example2.com/a.php' into your browser?

Comment: @symcbean : if I browse example2.com/a.php it works as a regular php file.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I have edited my question to include the firebug net output. please overview the question again.

Comment: Can you post the Apache virtual host configuration for your three hosts? I wonder if ServerName example1.com is the first and you have ServerName www.example2.com but not a ServerAlias for example2.com

Comment: I don't have ServerAlias in virtual host configuration for these three domains, Only ServerName.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. it was because of pound server configuration. 'RewriteLocation' entry in pound server configuration must be set to 2 to this server doesn't change the redirect location.

anyway, thank you for answering.